# How to add css immediately (display:none) to a block created through hook?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I created a block through drupal hook_block_info (and hook_block_view, but this doesn't really matter)

```
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['menu_mobile'] = array(
    'info' => t('Mobile Menu'),
    );
  return $blocks;
}
```

I need it to be hidden initially and then to show on webpage resize/mobile.
I did this by applying a display:none to css and the media rule

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

It works. Almost Perfectly. The problem is that, at the very beginning of webpage loading, the block is visible and, for maybe a second, it shows on its webpage, then the display:none does its work hiding it. It is annoying. I saw here some properties of the array to be returned by the hook, but none really fits my case. For example, enabling/disabling hides the block, but i don't really know how or when to show it again.

```
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7
```

So, how i can have the block initially hidden, or fasten the display:none (that is contained in the style.css of my custom theme)?

Answer (score 1):

A block can have a content element when created in code. This content element can be raw HTML or a drupal render array. If you use raw HTML for your block you can just put `<style type="text/css">#your-block-id { display: none;}</style>` directly into your block output.

Or if you use a render array you can do something similar with the `#attached` key on the render array. This is outlined in the API usage of drupal.org and a [comment provides an example](https://api.drupal.org/comment/44413#comment-44413):

```
$block['content'] = array(
  '#markup' => mymodule_testblock_content(),
  '#attached' => array(
      'css' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule.css',
      ),
      'js' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Obviously the render array approach is a cleaner, more elegant solution. You can even have the CSS `inline` when using `#attached`.

Comment: Good solutions! Unfortunately, yet too slow and the issue is still there.